# Ruby on rails - custom session using firestore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Implemented a custom session store using firestore.
One weird behavior I notice was when calling reset_session on logout, the whole session collection wiped-out.

Here is my custom session store:

```
require "google/cloud/firestore"

class FirestoreSessionStore < ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractSecureStore
  def initialize app, options = {}
    super

    @firestore = Google::Cloud::Firestore.new
    @col = @firestore.col "sessions"
  end

  def find_session _req, session_id
    return [generate_sid, {}] if session_id.nil?

    doc = @col.doc session_id
    fields = doc.get.fields || {}
    [session_id, stringify_keys(fields)]
  end

  def write_session _req, session_id, new_session, _opts
    doc = @col.doc session_id
    doc.set new_session, merge: true
    session_id
  end

  def delete_session _req, session_id, _opts
    doc = @col.doc session_id
    doc.delete
    generate_sid
  end

  def stringify_keys hash
    new_hash = {}
    hash.each do |k, v|
        new_hash[k.to_s] =
        if v.is_a? Hash
            stringify_keys v
        else
            v
        end
    end
    new_hash
  end
end
```

I am following this sample:
https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/session-handling-with-firestore